# How to assign unique DOM element ID

Tags: java, javascript, dom, gwt

My GWT application creates text areas, each of which must have an ID in order to be useful to a third-party JavaScript library. I know how to assign an ID to a GWT widget; I'm after a good way of generating those unique ID's.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For GWT, take a look at [HTMLPanel.createUniqueId](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLPanel.html#createUniqueId%28%29)

```
String id = HTMLPanel.createUniqueId();
```

Comment: The method in HTMLPanel calls the more generic version: `Document.get().createUniqueId();`, which is probably what you want to use and not create a dependency on the HTMLPanel widget if you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would be what you need for unique identifiers ( using a timestamp and the 'widget-' namespace ).

```
'widget-' + (new Date).valueOf()
```

Answer (score 1):

Java has a built-in class for unique ID creation: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

Another common way is by using a timestamp, i.e. `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: UUID is not implemented by GWT, but I found a guide for how to provide an implementation of your own: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModuleXml

I also found an implementation: http://2ality.blogspot.com/2009/01/uuids-for-gwt.html

Thanks for the headstart.

Comment: No worries! Btw, it looks like Chi's answer might be even more suitable for your purposes.

Comment: Yes, I think you're correct: HTMLPanel.createUniqueId seems to be exactly what I'm after.

Comment: Be careful using System.currentTimeMillis(), on many systems the granularity of the call is not precise up to the millisecond, and you end up with the same value even when called several milliseconds apart. Anyway, you can never ensure you will not have twice the same ID using that. A global counter you increment is probably much safer if you can afford to share it.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript:

```
var idIndex = 0;

function getNewId() {
    return "textGWT"+(idIndex++);
}
```

Java:

```
class IdMaker {

    private static int idIndex = 0;

    public static String generate() {
        return "textGWT"+(idIndex++);
    }
}
```